# Why an incoming call number is null in intent extra TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have a broadcast receiver defined with intent filter "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE". It mainly works just fine getting phone number from the intent, but sometimes, rather randomly, it fails on some phones. It looks like a some firmware bug. Does anybody experiences the same issue and know what the reason is actually, how to cope with it?

Answer (score -1):

I have used something like... And I had no problems with using of it...

```
            IntentService = new Intent(context, PlayService.class).setAction("outgoing_call");
            IntentService.putExtra("phone_number",intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER));            
            context.startService(IntentService);
```